# Send worksheet as attachment to email address list specified in workbook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, attachment

I am trying to get a subroutine that gets the email address list from one worksheet, then selects a different sheet in the same workbook and attaches it to an email.

This code below creates a new workbook with the sheet I need to copy and then debugs;

> Run-time error '53': File not found

And no Outlook email opens.

```vb
Sub SendAttachment()
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim sTo As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    
    'set email range
    
    Set emailRng = Workbooks("Paint Ordering List.xlsm").Worksheets("Email_List").Range("A3:A10")

    For Each cl In emailRng
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
    Next

    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

    Sheets("Order_List").Select

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With
    
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = sTo
        .CC = ""
        .bcc = ""
        .Subject = "Paint Order List"
        .Body = ""
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create a object reference to your attachment.

```
Dim MyAttachments As Object
Set MyAttachments = OutMail.Attachments
```

Second, you never actually save the worksheet you are looking to attach. So first save the worksheet with the naming convention you created and then your attachment needs to reference the full path. Not just the workbook name.

```
.Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
```